# Instead of LoadLevel, how do i use SceneManager

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I super new in coding and I couldn't find the right answer on the web. All I want is just change scene in my game. I've already had the buttons etc. But i can't choose the "menu" script from the On click function menus.

All answer is welcome!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {
public void ChangeScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** just plug in the `Menu` script to the left slot.

You have to attache `Menu` to a GameObject then plug that `GameObject` to the left slot.You will then be able to chose which script and function to send the event to on the right.

*The Image below shows the wrong way to do this(This is how you are currently doing it)*:

[image]

*The is the correct way to do it*:

[image]

You can also do this from code:

```
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button playButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Add Button Event
        playButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(playButton));
    }
    public void ChangeScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName");
    }

    private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == playButton)
        {
            ChangeScene("myscene");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here. First, the function "ChangeScene"

```
public void ChangeScene(string sceneName)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}
```

Then, you may have a problem in your scripts since you can't add any listener to the OnClick delegate. Fix every problem thrown by the console. A strange thing is that the name of the Menu script does not appear in the Menu component. Make sure the filename is "Menu.cs"

Finally, drag & drop the button into the field under "Runtime Only" and select "Menu > ChangeScene"